# Inserting query results into new table using loop instead of fetchall (Python, SQLite)

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to avoid using Python's `fetchall` method for inserting query results into a new SQLite table, as I encounter memory issues that will likely be avoided using either `fetchone` or `fetchmany`. However, when I try to loop through a query using a cursor, insertions only occur within one pass (in this case, inserting only the predefined 1000 rows as opposed to all). However, appending the loop results into an empty list results in all rows appended, so it's not as if it's the loop itself that is the issue.

The following script does not work:

```
   def fetchsome(cursor, some=1000):
       fetch = cursor.fetchmany
       while True:
           rows = fetch(some)
           if not rows: break
           for row in rows:
               cursor.execute("insert into zip4_upd values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", row)
       conn.commit()

   cur = conn.cursor()
   cur.execute("""select * from zip4 left outer join alias on zip4.primarykey = alias.primarykey left outer join detail on zip4.citystatekey = detail.detail_citystatekey""")
   fetchsome(cur)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [`executemany`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany)

```
cursor.executemany('''insert into zip4_upd values(
    ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
    ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
    ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
    ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
    ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
    ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', row_gen(cursor))
```

Instead, let `row_gen` be a generator that `yields` each row. This is lazy and should be memory efficient.

I'm a little hazy on your code, but something like this should be your `row_gen`

```
def row_gen(cursor, some=1000):
    fetch = cursor.fetchmany
    while True:
        rows = fetch(some)
        if not rows: break
        for row in rows:
            yield row
```

Presuming I understand the code correctly, you'll need to invoke `row_gen` correctly in the `executemany` call, so it ends with `... row_gen(cursor)`

Comment: Sorry, but how do I retrieve the `row` from a `yield` statement? If I want to call `row_gen` and use `row` to insert into the `zip4_upd` table, how can I go about doing so?

Comment: Basically, can you create an iterator that has all the values you want to insert? Understandably, lists can be big and memory hogs, which is why generators are awesome. Instead of creating the whole list and `return`ing that, it `yield`s each item in the iterable as needed.

Comment: Also, I'm a bit new to SQLite3 in Python, but maybe `row_gen` should use a different cursor than the `executemany`?

Comment: Ok, I used your suggestion, and called it using `cur.execute("INSERT INTO ZIP4_UPD VALUES(?,?...,?)", row_gen(cur))`,but I'm getting the error `ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type`. I then tried calling it using `for row in row_gen(cur):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO ZIP4_UPD VALUES(?,?...,?)", row)`, but that resulted in an empty table

Comment: Did you use `execute` or `executemany`? And just to make sure we're not falling prey to cursor misuse, make a second cursor `cur2` to feed to `row_gen`

Comment: Ok, `executemany` seems like the likely solution. Unfortunately, it's one problem after another for me. I'm now receiving the error message `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied.`, despite having checked and rechecked the number of columns and `?`s. However, this is a totally separate issue, so I'll accept your answer. Thanks for your help and patience, Prashant.